# Converting discord username and discriminator to id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a web app that allows users to enter their discord name and I would like to ping them using Discord.js webhooks.

When I run the following:

```
webhook.send("@username#1234");
```

With an appropriate name and discriminator, it comes out in chat as @username#1234 rather than changing to the blue "mention style" text and sending them a notification.

I understand that the desired behavior is possible using their ID instead of username but I would not like to ask all users to go through the process of finding that for me.

Is there a way to convert from name to ID programmatically or is there a syntax required when sending the message using the name and discriminator that I am unaware of?

Comment: You have to search your cache for users with the same username and discriminator, but you should be careful since users can still have the same username and discriminator.

Comment: I thought that the discriminator was what makes the name unique, so there can be 9999 people with the same name. If not, could you briefly explain how it works?

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, I was mistaken. You are correct. But you would still have to search your cache. You can't fetch a user by username + discriminator.